# CRM - Trigger onChange on a form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Currently working on CRM with JavaScript and i would like to trigger onChange event on whole form and not just on a field, i searched but couldn't find a solution to do that ..
Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: you mean onChange trigger of any field on a form or switch between forms using form switcher?

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you want to detect onChanage event of any field on the form, I think that only supported way is to add onChange on every field on form. But I know, if you have hundreds of fields it could take some time :)</del>

<del>Unsupported way is to add custom html web resource on form with javascript something like:</del>

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
somethingIsChanged=true;
});
```

<del>Prepare selector to detect all CRM form fields. Selecting field on CRM form on this way is unsupported.</del>

**EDIT**:

Actually I was partially wrong in first statement. There is a nice and elegant supported way to solve this. Add Javascript web resource something like:

```
function onPageLoadFunction()
{
    Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, index) {

        switch (control.getControlType()) {
            case "standard":
            case "lookup":
            case "optionset":
                var attribute = control.getAttribute();

                if (attribute != null) {                    
                    attribute.addOnChange(openAlertOnChange);
                }
                break;
        }                
    });    
}

function openAlertOnChange()
{
    alert("ON CHANGE alert");
}
```

In the form designer, set function '*onPageLoadFunction*' to be called on form load. If there is change of any field of specified type (standard, lookup, optionset) you will get alert from function '*openAlertOnChange*'. Cheers!

Comment: To Detect changes on form there is supported way : 

Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty()
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("").getIsDirty()
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml() 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data-entity/getdataxml

Comment: Agree. But to call getIsDirty() you need to have some trigger, and that is question in this thread.

Comment: Im not quite sure if the question isnt how to trigger onChange for all fields on the form. The answer would be to loop through attributes and call fireOnChange ;) but im not sure if thats the question

Comment: When you would loop through all attributes? If I understand well, that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this and call it for each attribute :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/attributes/fireonchange